# Laravel - Approach to store almost identical data

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a small system to control my rental properties. In this system, I want to be able to capture any regulations that can happen to a lease. A regulation can happen for:

- The rent amount
- The prepaid rent amount
- The prepaid deposit amount

I am thinking on how I can structure this. I have a `Lease` model with `leases` table (simplified):

```php
id | name       | address        | rent | prepaid_rent_amount | prepaid_deposit_amount
1  | Unit no. 1 | Highland Drive | 1000 | 3000                | 3000
```

In order to capture *if* any regulation has happened on the above three parameters (rent amount, prepaid rent or prepaid deposit), I need to store this in a database. The information needed to be capture from these parameters are almost identical:

```
//Regulation in rent
 - lease_id
 - amount
 - date
 - flag

//Regulation in prepaid rent
 - lease_id
 - amount
 - date

//Regulation in prepaid deposit
 - lease_id
 - amount
 - date
```

## Solution 1

I was thinking to create a model/table for each parameter, and simply just store data relevant for each regulation in the corresponding table:

- `RentRegulation`
- `PrepaidRentRegulation`
- `PrepaidDepositRegulation`

I think the benefits of this solution is that the data is separated, however it feels like it is bloating my codebase.

## Solution 2

Instead of creating three models/tables to store the above information in, I was thinking to just create one model:

- `Regulation`

An inside this model, simply have a column called `type`. The value for this column would then control what kind of regulation we were talking about (e.g. `RentRegulation`, `PrepaidRentRegulation` etc.)

The only concern I have for solution #2, is for the type `RentRegulation` there can be different types of regulations. So a rent can be regulated due to the following stuff (all regulated by law):

- Increase in inflation
- Renovating the lease
- Agreement with the tenant that rent should increase

To cater for the above, I was thinking of also adding a nullable `flag` column to the `regulations` table, and then just rely on scopes when retreiving data?

Comment: opinion based question. You are the coder you know what is better for you.

Comment: Very interesting question.  I run into this a lot too, and tend to use #2, along with the nullable extra column.  Curious what others think.

Comment: @Watercayman That's also what I tend to do, without really thinking much about it. (Even though, when thinking about it, I believe solution #1 is much more explicit) I was also just curious to see if there is any best practices on these sort of scenarios.

Comment: I'd tend to solution #1 as well. Separates the concerns and is better suited to isolated modifications. Especially if legislation is involved (which can always be subject to change) it might happen that additional logic needs to be implemented for e.g. PrepaidRentRegulation. Also looking at the "raw" tables is easier to understand once they are separated. No need to understand why which field is nulled etc.